# Right hand column in Spring Boot Admin details displaying off screen

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-admin

We are using Spring Boot Admin in Kubernetes in AWS (EKS), as a result our services are deploying with a lot of metadata on them, including `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration`.  This large field is causing SPA to render the page with the right hand column (the one with the health metrics, threads and non-heap memory) to render of the visible screen with no scroll bar at the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to control what metadata fields SBA displays, or what metadata fields are included in the microservices that we are deploying?

Currently I have a work around of editing the CSS attached to the section tag inside the div with class `instances__view` to have a fixed pixel width to match my screen, but this needs to be done every time.

> *Versions:* 
>   Spring Boot Admin: *2.1.3* 
>  other spring boot
>   services *2.1.2* and *2.1.3* 
>  Spring Cloud version: *Greenwich.RELEASE*
>   
>  Kubernetes version: *1.11.5 (EKS)*

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Spring Boot Admin version 2.1.4 released on 2019/04/05